# Vector with index and iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I just wanted to ask what is happening here, where am I going wrong?

```
vector<int> a(5);

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)    cin>>a[i];            //Input is 1 2 3 4 5

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)    cout<<a[i]<<" ";      //Prints correct, 1 2 3 4 5
cout<<endl;

for(VI::iterator it = a.begin(); it!=a.end(); ++it) {
    cout<<a[*it]<<" ";                          //Prints incorrect output
}
cout<<endl;
```

Looks like, the last element in the incorrect output is `a[*(a.end()-1)]` and the first element is missing from what it should actually be.

Comment: Shouldn't the output line be `cout<<*it<<" ";`?

Comment: Instead of `a[*it]`, use simply `*it`. The reason being is that `it` is an iterator already pointing to the value in `a`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

correct way to print is

```
 cout<<*it<<" ";
```

*it gives value pointed by vector. In your case a[*it] = a[1] for first iteration, a[2] for second iteration ans so on. at end invalid number will be printed. Its the reason for missing first number.
Your trying to print a[1] a[2], a[3],a[4],

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. In fact, it misses the point of the question entirely.

Comment: @juanchopanza. completed my explanation now.

Answer (score 4):

By calling `*it` you are getting the value at that iterator (which is what I think you want to output).  You're current code is actually doing:

```
a[1]
a[2]
a[3]
a[4]
a[5] // not an element in the vector - undefined behaviour
```

What I think you actually want is:

```
cout<<*it<<" ";
```

Comment: @stefan good point, I've corrected my mistake (and cursed my off by one error :p)

Comment: Wonderful, I'll delete my original comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

What happens here

```
for(VI::iterator it = a.begin(); it!=a.end(); ++it) {
  cout<<a[*it]<<" "; // *it is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
}
```

is that `it` is an iterator to each element of the vector, and `*it` dereferences the iterator, giving the value of the element. 
Since the indices and the values stored are almost the same in this case, this almost works. You are looping from a[1] to a[5], missing the first element, and then going out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Iterator is not an index to a vector. It is an object that points to an element of the vector and has overloaded dereference operator that yields the value of the element pointed by that iterator.

When you do `a[*it]`, you essentially use the value of an element stored in the vector (pointed by `it`) as an index to that array. In other words, you are referencing elements 2 though 6, and also invoke undefined behavior because there is no 6th element in your vector.

You have probably meant to write `cout<<*it<<" ";`  instead of `cout<<a[*it]<<" ";`. Or, alternatively, given your data set in that vector, you could do `cout<<a[*it - 1]<<" ";` in order to access elements 1 through 5 by using index 0 through 4.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!